# When I do an excel output from R, the decimal disappears in the column?

Tags: r, excel, output

It seems that when I use the `write.csv2` function to export my table from R to .csv, the decimals disappear.

For instance:

df in R:

```
id  customer value

[1] AAAAAAA 0.2345
```

when I export the output to Excel using import data

```
id  customer value

[1] AAAAAAA 2345
```

Anyway to mitigate this issue?

Comment: what does it look like when you open the .csv file as a text file rather than opening it in excel?

Comment: export it as a text file?

Comment: `write.csv2` uses commas as the decimal separator (and semicolons as field separator)  Are you sure your version of Excel recognizes this?

Comment: @the_one_neuron it shows as scientific notation... for example `0.384575392999102` value shows as `3.84575E+14`, which is why it gets messed up when I import it to Excel

Comment: @Mike: client requirement to do .csv unfortunately